# Deserializing java date into Instant

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, java-time, date

I need to deserialize below two foramt into `java.time.Instant` in a singe code

`2020-04-23T10:51:24.238+01:00` and
`2019-11-11T15:44:10.201Z`

I'm getting belwow error in first case

nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String "2020-04-23T10:51:24.238+01:00": com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.Instant` from String "2020-04-23T10:51:24.238+01:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.Instant: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-04-23T10:51:24.238+01:00' could not be parsed at index 23

Is there any solution ?
Also Is there any way to deserialize `java.util.Date` into `java.time.Instant` 
Note : Its an API response and  I can't use Date in deserialized class i.e consumer

Comment: Clear your question what you want give an example input output and describe your senerio

Comment: Are you using any deserializer ?

Comment: No, its  simple rest client. scnario is simple, I get one of above two fomat in response, I want to populate it into `Instant` variable, without changing name/adding other variable

Comment: You are doing rest call from your application and response has two format, you just want to parse the string to Instant right?

Comment: `class response { Instant date ; } `;  see , this is my response class in which I'm getting date in either one of above 2 formats

Answer (score 1):

```
    String dateString = "2020-04-23T10:51:24.238+01:00";    

    Instant deserializedInstant = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
            .parse(dateString, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(deserializedInstant);
```

Output is:

> 2020-04-23T09:51:24.238Z

It works for your other string too:

```
    String dateString = "2019-11-11T15:44:10.201Z";
```

> 2019-11-11T15:44:10.201Z

Your JSON library may have still more elegant solutions. If not, you can probably wrap the above in a custom JSON deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

> Also Is there any way to deserialize java.util.Date into java.time.Instant

Know your API:

```
final java.util.Date date = new Date();
final java.time.Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

Comment: Can't use `java.util.Date`  It has  to be  java.time.Instant

Comment: I simply quoted from your question, maybe you should correct that